# How to optimize performance for dimension attributes?

Tags: ssas, cube, dimension

I'm looking to enhance the cube processing time and someone suggested me to set "AttributeHierarchyEnabled='False'" for attributes which were not used at user defined hierarchies but I'm not clear with the "AttributeHierarchyEnabled" property and it's functionalities.

Can anybody just explain me when to set

> AttributeHierarchyEnabled='True'

and

> AttributeHierarchyEnabled='False'

and it's effects ?

Also I would like to know the use of "AttributeHierarchyVisible" and "IsAggregatable" properties.

Please give me some information about it which is going to be very useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166717.aspx) states:

> The value of the **AttributeHierarchyEnabled** property determines whether an attribute hierarchy is created. If this property is set to **False**, the attribute hierarchy is not created and the attribute cannot be used as a level in a user hierarchy; the attribute hierarchy exists as a member property only. However, a disabled attribute hierarchy can still be used to order the members of another attribute. If the value of the **AttributeHierarchyEnabled** property is set to **True**, the value of the **AttributeHierarchyVisible** property determines whether the attribute hierarchy is visible independent of its use in a user-defined hierarchy.

- *IsAggregatable*

> By default, an (All) level is defined for all attribute hierarchies. To disable the (All) level for an enabled attribute hierarchy, set the value for this property to **False**.
>   
>   If we set **AttributeHierarchyEnabled** to **False**, we cannot add that Attribute to a user defined hierarchy, we restrain SSAS from making any MOLAP-storage optimizations for this attribute. When we use such attributes in an MDX query as Attribute Hierarchy, we get no results. Although we can still use this as a member property in a query using

```
 Member_Expression.Properties(Property_Name [, TYPED])
```

According to Dustin Ryan's post:

> This will prevent end users from slicing with the attribute, reducing storage requirements and increasing performance.

If we set **AttributeHierarchyVisible** to **False**, the Attribute Hierarchy is active but stays hidden when a user browses the cube while you can still use it in MDX query.

If we set **IsAggregatable** to **False**, SSAS does not create the aggregated *All* member for us for that attribute.

Relevant MSDN thread that might be useful:
[Dimension attribute with AttributeHierarchyEnabled=true and AttributeHierarchyVisible=false](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7ffd07c4-2d63-45e2-a279-2b2a68b78776/dimension-attribute-with-attributehierarchyenabledtrue-and-attributehierarchyvisiblefalse?forum=sqlanalysisservices)